# Apache - limit scope of RequestReadTimeout

Tags: apache

We are running apache and using nagios to query http for alerting / monitoring purposes. We have a few webservers that required more sensitive settings for mod_reqtimeout.c and on those servers we periodically / sporadically get alerts about "UNKNOWN 500 read timeout". Nothing is actually wrong with the webserver / apache when this is happening and we think we have narrowed down the problem to our relatively strict settings for:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=
```

We have quite a few vhosts configured on some of these servers and are trying to find a way to modify our global header read timeout setting to ignore certain IP addresses, for example the IP address of our nagios server.

Otherwise a way to have it only apply to certain domains, without having to specifically add the setting into every vhost entry where it needs to exist.

Is there a resource available that talks about how to limit a global parameter to ignore certain IPs or page requests?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can define the timeout at both the *server config* and *virtual host* level, in my testing with Apache 2.4.41 I wasn't able to apply a configuration at the *server config* level and then override it at the *virtual host*. It just continued to apply the *server config* values. So I ended up increasing values in the *server config*.

If you are on Ubuntu then you probably have defaults defined in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/reqtimeout.conf` for the whole server which then means you aren't able to set values for a *virtual host* without first changing the configuration here.

There's a short thread about this on the [apache users list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/apache-users/msg117922.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation][1]

[1]: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html, you should be able to override the global config in vhost config.

`Context:   server config, virtual host`